# Does MongoDB update operation support the batch commit?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

when I update MongoDB like this:

```
    collection.update(query,data,true,false);
```

every time I just can submit one update operation to mongo, the performance is very bad. like this operation, Does it have batch commit operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that in "modern drivers" then yes it does, and that is the intent of modern driver releases.

What we are talking about here is usage of the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) introduced in MongoDB 2.6. At the time of introduction, tools such as the MongoDB "shell" introduced usage of these methods ( even as "singular" operations ) "under the hood" so to speak, so that those methods where actually called where the server version was deemed to support it via the appropriate tests.

With the MongoDB 3.0.x release series, the drivers have been "overhauled" to implement methods that makes use of these "Bulk API" methods where appropriate in a similar manner.

The general approach is different signatures, such as `.update_one()` or similar in various situations. Also these often as observed from "different classes" to the "legacy" implementations existing in previous driver versions.

So the modern and "evolving" consideration is to utilize these methods by default for new methods where applicable. But also to "distinguish" between methods so as to not cause backward compatibility breaks where possible.

You can use "Bulk" methods either explicitly where they are allowed by both driver version and server compatibility, or by using the "new" methods in more modern drivers, as is appropriate to what you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in MongoDB it is known as a Bulk operation.

You can execute a bulk find & update operation that finds all records matching a query and update the results accordingly.

Here is an example from [MongoDB's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update)

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).update( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } } );
bulk.find( { item: null } ).update( { $set: { item: "TBD" } } );
bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for that - I'll amend my comment.